# Auto Increment Table causes Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, database, merge, auto-increment

I am working on a migration script which merges two billing systems into one, importing the essential data from a remote DB into a local DB. This is working excellent with the exception of this error message. It is unfortunately causing quite a few records to be missed.

Example:

```
ERROR: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' INSERT INTO tblproductconfigoptionssub (`id`,`configid`,`optionname`,`sortorder`,`hidden`) values ('500349','500046','Coppermine','6','0')
```

Code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproductconfigoptionssub WHERE configid = '$configoptionid_old'";
    $res_configoptionssub = $db2->query($sql);

    while ($configoptionssub = $res_configoptionssub->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $configoptionssub[0] = $configoptionssub[0] + WHMCS_ID_INCREMENT; // Auto Increment ID by flat value
        $configoptionssub[1] = $configoptionid_new;

        $configoptionsub_vals = implode("','", $configoptionssub);
        $configoptionsub_vals = "'" . $configoptionsub_vals . "'";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblproductconfigoptionssub ($col_configoptionssub) values ($configoptionsub_vals)";
        $db1->query($sql);
```

[image]

For many of the rows, I need to increment the ID by a flat value, which is the purpose of **WHMCS_ID_INCREMENT** What exactly am I doing wrong that is causing this?

Comment: Imo, you should never set an `auto increment key` column in an insert statement.  It can and will confuse the database engine and possibly the programmer. So, while you look after the `id` column - remove the 'auto increment property and 'replace` it later and you can set the next available value to the correct value in the dictionary?

Comment: That makes complete sense, although do you think that is actually causing this problem? It seems to work for about 95% of the rows, but I get this error for the remaining 5%, why I was thinking it was likely something else.

Comment: You probably have an error - to detect that just add a pre insert trigger that check if you pass zero and report the column values. The other issue of modifying the id when auto-increment when it is set - is that the next value to use may not be maintained correctly - you should set that yourself  when you alter the table to auto-increment after you have finished the processing.